# PyCharm packages issue

Tags: terminal, python, macports

I'm using PyCharm as Python IDE, on macOS High Sierra and my default Python version is 3.6.5,

I have a big issue within packages using PyCharm. As an example of my issue, I have installed `Pillow` using `pip3 install Pillow`

But, in PyCharm I'm not able to use it and PyCharm is thinking I did not install the Pillow package, and I had to install it through PyCharm package management.

But I don't like to continue developing like this, my question is, how should I force PyCharm to use packages that I installed through `pip3` ?

Comment: You need to change your interpreter settings to use your Python distribution where you installed your package. PyCharm probably created a virtualenv for your project, which is a different repo and doesn't include packages from your default python installation. You'' find your interpreter under settings. Moreover, the settings page allows you to install packages from PyCharm directly, so you could use that instead of `pip`. Dependencies will be solved automatically and you won't encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Goto PyCharm > Preferences (COMMAND+,) > Project > Python Interpreter.
There should be a dropdown to select the required version of Python interpreter. Select your version of Python interpreter from the dropdown. If the required option does not exist, click show all and select your required version (Check to see the exact path of the python interpreter).